# How to write Pyspark dataframe to json with partitions and without column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know something similar has been asked before but I can't seem to figure it out. I partition by the listed columns to create directories in s3 but my `payload` column contains the actual data I need. Previous answers stated to save as text but that doesn't work since I have a MapType and need the file to be json.

Code Used:

```
(
    df
    .write
    .format('json')
    .partitionBy("country_code", "state_code", "size")
    .mode("append")
    .save('/mnt/dev/test')
)
```

Current Output:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "100": {
            "cumulative_ttl_sold": 11,
            "cumulative_ttl_returned": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "100": {
        "cumulative_ttl_sold": 11,
        "cumulative_ttl_returned": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your df and schema look like before partition? Please provide a bigger sample size for better understanding.

Comment: Also, when you read it back, it will be a lot of work to get it back under a column named "payload". Simple JSON import will create a column for each "100" like entry.